# How can I make Apple Mail show the URL (in mails) when I hover over a link?

Tags: url, ios

There is a related question for Safari but I am interested in a solution for Mail. The ⌘View menu.

I am using OS X 10.10.5, and I would really like to see the real full link I would follow, especially with potential phishing mails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just hover the cursor over the link for a few seconds. The full URL will spring up underneath.

The down arrow that will also appear next to the link will open it in a Quick Look window rather than a browser - but if you want to check the link is safe first, don't use that until you're sure.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was to impatient. Thanks. Is there a way to reduce the time of showing this textbox?

Comment: Not that I can find, sorry [doesn't mean there may not be one, just my Google-Fu wasn't strong enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in macOS Big Sur, this feature changed.  No matter how long you hover over a link in Mail, the URL and link preview won't appear until you *Force Click* (press harder until you feel the second click) on a track pad.  If you are using a mouse, press the option key, and the URL and link preview arrow will appear.

Comment: Such a great present for scammers! Phishing with hidden link URLs is soooo waaaay more easier :)))